# Organize integers by size?

Tags: c++, int

I am relatively new to C++, and I am in need of some advice. I will try to keep it short. What is the simplest and best way of organizing integer values by their size? Then, I want to be able to use that information. My goal is basically, I can get an integer from a source, and then I want to organize the sources by the size of the integer value, and if two different sources has the same value I want the program to perform a bunch of code. Hopefully that made sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(By the size I mean the value, sorry for any inconvenience)

EDIT:
I don't have a sample code to show off unfortunately, but I will try to clarify what I am aiming for. I want to compare the speed of between 2-20 "characters" in a game. The fastest one will go first in the next part of the game, followed by the second fastest etc. If 2 "characters" has the same speed I want their starting position to be randomized (between them two). I have most of this pictured in my head, but I am mostly struggling to figure out how to sort the speed and know who had the highest speed value.

Comment: What do you call the size of an integer ?

Comment: *Hopefully that made sense* Sorry but it does not make sense to me what you want to do.  What do you mean by size?  Value?

Comment: By "organizing integers by size", do you mean sorting?

Comment: @Fabian You should clarify if you mean the actual value of an integer, or the size of the type (e.g. like `int`, `long`, `long long`, etc.).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I basically just mean "Int a=5", then 5 is the value.

Comment: @Fabian As mentioned [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36629133/edit) your question to give additional information please. Next step would also to clarify, what should be _the source_ of that value.

Comment: @Fabian Best would be you give a sample code of what you've already tried and where you're stuck actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Have no code unfortunately, but I tried to specify what it was needed for. Do you, or anyone else, have any useful advice? Or am I still too unclear?

Comment: @Fabian Start out explaining that to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: size of `int`s are always the same so organize them by size is pointless. If you want to sort by value, that's a completely different thing

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort
```

Simple usage:

```
// intArray will be replaced by your collection of integers.
const int SIZE = 7;
int intArray[SIZE] = {5, 3, 32, -1, 1, 104, 53};

std::sort(intArray, intArray + SIZE);

cout << "Sorted Array looks like this." << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i)
    cout << intArray[i] << " ";
```

This should print: `-1 1 3 5 32 53 104`

This article might be some help if you are new to stl: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Agreed, but easily converted into an answer. Summarize the basic points of the article so that should the article move or the host site go belly up the answer still has value.

Comment: @user4581301 _"but easily converted into an answer"_ May be not the correct one. I'm still not sure if OP is really asking for sorting.

Comment: Made for a good exercise in formulating a complete answer even if it turns out to be the wrong answer. Ammar, once more recommendation: add a line to show the state of the array after sorting just to hammer the point home.

Answer (score 0):

If the integers have to be unique (not 2 times the same integer in the container) and sorted, you might want to use a `set`

The next part of your question isn't very clear, but I'll try anyway.
If you want to know if a certain integer is already in your container, the best way is to go through said container and test every element, to do that a `vector` would do I guess, but since ordering is important, I would rather use a `set` or a `priority_queue`, but those are a little bit more complicated.

Now there's the "source" part. By source, do you mean input from exterior sources ? I think that's what you mean anyway. Basically you want a container storing "sources" by their values in ascending order, and when two get to the same value, do something.

The most natural and optimized way to do this would be to make your sources objects, and to overload the < operator in those objects, and then in that operator you can test if those objects have the same value to execute your 'bunch of code'.

Here a sample :

```
class Source
{
private:
  int m_value; // The value of this source
public:
  Source(int const& v) // setting the source's value
  {
    setValue(v);
  }
  int getValue() // Returns the sources value for comparison
  {
    return m_value;
  }
  int setValue(int const& v) // Sets the source's value
  {
    m_value = v;
  }

  // ... [Insert other methods here]

  bool operator<(Source const& s) // Testing which source has the lowest value
  {
    if(m_value == s.m_value()) // If their values are equal
    {
      // Your code
    }
    return (m_value < s.m_value()); // Else we test if the other value's bigger
  }
};
```

And then you can store these in a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), for example.